# Registrar dato con fecha en php

Tags: php, html, postgresql

Buenos dias señores espero que me puedan ayudar, estoy haciendo un sistema de control de asistencia para un preescolar, el sistema lo desarrollo ya que es un requisito de la universidad. Mi duda es como registrar la hora ingresando la cedula o nombre del personal.

Comment: considera compartir el código de lo que llevas o intentaste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimo que al colocar cedula/nombre del personal, se va a crear un registro. Al registro que se vaya a crear, tenes que agregarle un campo con el tipo de dato `timestamp`, esto agregara automáticamente el valor de la fecha y hora actual del momento en el que se crea el registro. Tené en cuenta que vas a tener que configurar el `timezone` de tu servidor para que la fecha y la hora coincida con la del tu país.

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: Muchas gracias mani, me documente mas sobre el tema y con lo que me dijiste me sirvio.